# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /home/anis/OrangeFormation/resources/views/admin.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

can anyone help??

this is my controller method:

```
 public function index()
{
    $formations = Formation::latest()->paginate(5);
    return view('formation', compact('formations'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

and my blade is: 
[my blade code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLjtq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
foreach ($variables as $variable)
```

Here `$variables` is something iterable. In your example, it's an empty string if the `$variables` is `null`. So you got the error. `$variables` can not be an empty string. In your blade you should only do the `foreach` if the `$variables` is not `null`